# Security issues in oracle ucm

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-ucm

I have installed web content server (UCM) 12c and config the provider with active directory(AD) the problem occur when i login to ucm  with my user i cannot see the folder it invisible to my user  which has already permission group in AD and Account in ucm with the same name of group ,  Note that I gave (R) read permission to the group. please any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

After logging in to the Ucm server, from the profile check if the right role which is assigned in AD is listed there .

Most likely in this case the role is not correctly assigned.